# boolean return a null - flutter

Tags: flutter, boolean

I am new to flutter and want to return a boolean in the following method

```
@override
bool isConnectedToInternet() {
bool network;
check().then((internet) {
 if (internet != null && internet) {
  network = true;
  print("connected");
 }else {
  network = false;
  print("not connected");
 }
});
print(network.toString());
return network;
```

}

when I run the code, the print is working but the final return gives me null. how to solve this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. You want to start an asynchronous method, **not wait for it's result** and still return that result you never cared to wait for. You have to wait for the result, there is no other option.

I don't know what you *want* to do, but what you need to do is this:

```
Future<bool> isConnectedToInternet() async {
  var internet = await check();
  return (internet != null && internet);
}
```

If that does not work out with your method declaration you want to override, maybe you need to change that.

Comment: i was returning a bool internet wheres i needed to return Future<bool>internet. modified the code and it worked like a charm.